# Kubernetes on mixed os Linux and windows with Calico opensource

Tags: linux, windows, kubernetes, calico

I came across an [article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/adding-windows-nodes/) which States that we can have mixed os in cluster.

Article talk about having flannel as networking plugin but i want to use Calico opensource plugin instead as it provides encryption.

Any idea if this is possible using Calico opensource?

Answer (score 1):

Calico for Windows does exist https://www.tigera.io/tigera-products/calico-for-windows/

But it appears to be a commercial product so you would probably want to contact them to ask about it. Assuming it's equivalent to normal Calico, I don't see any reason it wouldn't work. BGP and IPIP are both standardized protocols that aren't specific to any OS.